try/except не работает
Почему try/except не работает? Почему не обработалась ошибка?
print(2)

fruits = ['lime', 'banana', 'apple']

fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, x = fruits

try:
    for k in fruit2:

        if type(k) is str:
            print(True)

except:
    print('ошибка!')

ошибка: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ramazan0408/Рабочий стол/Python/Самообучение/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, x = fruits
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)


Потому что ошибка вообще не в try/except блоке. В списке fruits всего 3 элемента, а в строке ниже вы пытаетесь распаковать его в 4 переменных. Уберите x. Да и цикл находящийся в try/except вам не нужен, в переменной fruit2 всего 1-ин элемент должен быть судя по логике.

Вы наверно хотели команду
fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, x = fruits

т.е. команду в которой может возникнуть ошибка, поместить в влок try:
print(2)

fruits = ['lime', 'banana', 'apple']

try:
    fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, x = fruits       # <--- здесь может возникнуть ошибка

    for k in fruit2:

        if type(k) is str:
            print(True)
except:
    print('ошибка!')

Вывод:

2
ошибка!



Ааааа, спасибо.

@Максим Смирнов, не стоит. Между прочим, когда мой ответ был для вас полезным, вы можете принят его (клик на галочку возле него). См. Что делать с ответами на вопрос?
